# Why abs are small?how can i make them bigger

Tags: workout

I am a thin guy but my abs are visible but there are small.I workout on floor my back face down my hands touching the head and I move up until the height of knees and I go back again.I am doing everyday at least 35minutes.I eat well nutritient etc. How can I increase those abs to be big?thanks

Comment: How do you work on your back face down?

Answer (score 2):

There's no one particular exercise that will force your abs to grow.  Each of us reacts to exercise stimulus in our own way.  Couple that with abs being a typically stubborn body part for most people, the best you can do is continue to train them with variety and consistency.  A search on a site like [ExRx](http://www.exrx.net/) should provide plenty of exercises to try.

When comparing a particular body part, you should consider symmetry, balance, proportion, and aesthetics as well as size.  Everyone has their own perception of what a particular body part should look like.  However, we are all limited by a few factors.  Those factors tend to be genetics, recovery, nutrition, and sleep to name a few.  If your goal is to increase the muscle girth of your abs, you should consider how that would affect the rest of your body.  Will having large abs upset the rest of your physique in terms of symmetry, balance, proportion, etc.?  Often, taking a look at the “bigger picture” helps to set individual body part goals.